# Variance components model: proportions of within and between variance are off?

Tags: r, variance, repeated-measures, lavaan

I was hoping someone could help me see what I'm obviously missing here.

I simulated some clustered data and, in the sense of a variance component model, wanted to take a look at the variances of the level 2 and level 1 residuals. My model stipulated that it should be about 50-50 (see rho = 0.5)
*(Now with libraries)*:

```
library( mvtnorm)
library( dplyr)
library( reshape2)
library( lavaan) 

set.seed( 123); gen_cluster <- function( param = c( 0.1, 0.5), n = 6000, n_cluster = 2000, rho = 0.5) {

  Sigma_i <- matrix( c( 1, 0, 0, 1 - rho), ncol = 2) 
  values_i <- rmvnorm( n = n, sigma = Sigma_i)

  cluster_name <- rep( 1:n_cluster, each = n / n_cluster)
  Sigma_cl <- matrix( c( 1, 0, 0, rho), ncol = 2)
  values_cl <- rmvnorm( n = n_cluster, sigma = Sigma_cl)

  x <- values_i[ , 1] + rep( values_cl[ , 1], each = n / n_cluster)

  error <- values_i[ , 2] + rep( values_cl[ , 2], each = n / n_cluster)

  y <- param[ 1] + param[ 2]*x + error 

  df <- data.frame( x, y, cluster = cluster_name)
  return( df)
}

df <- gen_cluster()
```

Because I'm only interested in the error components, I will just look at the x variable. I expected intuitively, that if I calculated the per-subject means and then subtracted each observation from that, I would get my $u_j$ and $e_{ij}$, so to speak. Because the level 1 and level 2 errors are uncorrelated, $Var(x_{ij})=Var(u_j) + Var(e_{ij})$.

So I did that:

```
xmean <- aggregate( df, by = list( df$cluster), 
                    FUN = mean,  na.rm = TRUE) 
df <- merge( df, xmean, by = 'cluster')
df <- df[ , c( 1, 2, 3, 5)]
df$x_c <- df$x.x - df$x.y
df <- df %>% rename( x = x.x, y = y.x, xmean = x.y)
```

But the variance R is giving me is off, as far as I can tell: 
$Var(u_j) = 1.34$ and $Var(e_{ij}) = 0.67$. In sum, they add up to the exact variance of the original variable: $Var(x)=2.01$ but the proportions are off (about 66-33 instead of 50-50).

I made a wide-dataset and ran some intercept-only types of models in lavaan (FE and MLM) to try and confirm this and they are giving me the right variances.

```
# Make wide dataset for lavaan model 1 (lavm1)

df$xvar <- rep( seq( 1, 3, 1), length( df$cluster)/3)

dfwide <- dcast( df, cluster ~ xvar, value.var = 'x')

name <- c( 'cluster', 'x1', 'x2', 'x3')
names( dfwide) <- name

dfwide$xmean <- rowMeans( dfwide[ , -1])

# Models 

lavm1 <- '
alpha =~ 1*x1 + 1*x2 + 1*x3 
'
lavm2 <- '
level: 1
alphaw =~ x
level: 2
alphab =~ x
'
summary( fit_lavm1 <- sem( lavm1, data = dfwide))
summary( fit_lavm2 <- sem( lavm2, data = df, cluster = 'cluster')) # Forgot the cluster argument
```

```
FE (lavm1)
         Estimates  Std.Err.  z-value  P(>|z|)    
alpha    0.986      0.043     23.426   0.000
x1       1.014      0.042     23.134   0.000
x2       0.976      0.044     23.597   0.000
x3       1.031      0.042     23.225   0.000 

MLM (lavm2)
         Estimates  Std.Err.  z-value  P(>|z|)    
alphaw   1.007
alphab   0.986
```

Which is giving me the expected result: an average within variance (averaged over the 3 waves in the wide dataset) of about 1.0 and a between variance of also around 1.0 (Note on edit: originally I had simulated 5 waves but used only 3 in the post for the sake of simplicity - in making the code more transparent, I changed it to really only simulate 3 waves - that's why the values in the table above are now slightly different).

I am sure I'm just overlooking something obvious, but I've been staring at the problem too long to find it for myself. I would very much appreciate some help!

Comment: Hi Hendogg87, welcome to crossvalidated. Please qualify your variable names, and/or add library statements - I'm not familiar with rmvnorm, and I don't know what package it's from. So when I paste your code into R, it doesn't run.

Comment: I came across a function in the dae package called rmvnorm(), but I don't think that's what you're using.

Comment: Hi Jeremy, thanks so much for the reply. I added the libraries at the top of the code in the post. I also did not include the code for making the wide dataset because I was trying to be brief. I can post the entire code though if it helps. Either way, the second MLM lavaan model uses the original long dataset so that should run as is.

Comment: Error in lavaan::lavaan(model = lavm1, data = dfwide, model.type = "sem",  : 
  object 'dfwide' not found

Comment: Hi again Jeremy, thanks for your patience. I have now included the code to create the wide dataset and corrected an oversight with the second model - I had forgotten the 'cluster' argument. I just tested the three code blocks myself in a new R script, so it should all run now!

Comment: Thanks. I think the issue is the small number of members of each cluster. The multilevel approach is dividing by N-1.

Comment: Hi again Jerermy, thanks for the help. You were right about the denominator. I guess it makes sense that R wasn't using the proper degrees of freedom to calculate the variance. Still, the between variance is not adding up. By hand, I calculated the total, within and between sum of squares and the (I thought) proper degrees of freedom: sst = 14396.45, ssw = 2400.806, ssb = 11995.65 with df_sst = 2499, df_ssw = 2000, df_ssb = 499. This makes sense because ssw + ssb = sst, and df_ssw + df_ssb = df_sst. But 11995.65 / 449 = 24.03937 which is way too high... I will keep at it...